# How to address both males and females in a letter

Tags: greetings

How to write the address in a letter when the recipients of the letter are a combination of  males and females? Imagine that you had a meeting with a couple of your colleagues,  males and females and then you draft minutes and you wanna send the letter to each one of the participants.  So what do you put in " CC" in the letter Mr.A, Mrs. B, Mr. C etc

Comment: Do you mean "to whom it may concern"?

Comment: Do you mean the *address*, like "John Smith, 123 Main Street"*, or [the salutation](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/greetings_and_s.html)* like "Dear Mr. Smith"?  [In the *cc:* section, we don't usually use titles like Mr. or Mrs. at all, just "John Smith", "Jane Doe" and so forth.](http://business.uni.edu/buscomm/writtenbuscomm/business%20letter%20format.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use:

"Dear Mesdames/Messrs.,"

Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to expound this answer (you may proceed to research on your own or wait for other better answers.)

**NOTE:** Business writing should be **succinct** to begin with.

On your question - re: CC: to person A, person B, person C, why not just indicate in the letter that copies were provided to all the 'members', 'attendees', etc.? [whichever is appropriate]

**NOTE:** A list of attendees and absentees is normally included in minutes of meetings.